# Javascript math

Tags: javascript, math

```
function opacityChange(element, action)
{

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        element.style.opacity = parseFloat(element.style.opacity);
        if(action)
        {
            if(element.style.opacity < 1) element.style.opacity += 0.1;
            else clearInterval(timer);
        }
        else
        {
            if(element.style.opacity > 0) element.style.opacity -= 0.1;
            else clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 100);

    return true;
}
```

[image]

[image]

everything was fine when I hide the picture, but when I try to show it JS can't add 0.1 to 0.1.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what it does, what the problem is, and what the question is ?

Comment: @adeneo, I want to know why this is happening

Comment: Why what is happening? There's no description and no real question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element.style.opacity = parseFloat(element.style.opacity);` doesn't do what you might expect.

`element.style.opacity` will be casted into a string on assignment by the browser. It won't be a float, or a JavaScript `Number`.

Therefore, you are actually adding a `string` with a `number`. Which means you are not doing `0.1 + 0.1`. You are actually doing `"0.1" += 0.1`.

`element.style.opacity = 0.5; //element.style.opacity == "0.5"`
`element.style.opacity += 0.5; //element.style.opacity == "0.50.5"`

The reason why it works when you hide it, is because if the string is can be parsed as a number, then the browser will parse the string into a number when you do subtraction.

```
var a = "1" - 0.5; // a == 0.5 because "1" can be parsed into a Number
var a = "a" - 0.5; // a == NaN because "a" cannot be parsed into a number
```

I'd suggest you do the following:

```
function opacityChange(element, action)
{

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        //this does nothing.
        //element.style.opacity = parseFloat(element.style.opacity);

        // do this instead
        var opacity = parseFloat(element.style.opacity);

        if(action)
        {
            // notice the change in condition and assignment
            if(opacity < 1) element.style.opacity = opacity + 0.1;
            else clearInterval(timer);
        }
        else
        {
            // notice the change in condition and assignment
            if(opacity > 0) element.style.opacity = opacity - 0.1;
            else clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 100);

    return true;
}
```